# R: How to increase spaces between y axis ticks?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis

How do I increase the distance between ticks on the Y axis in R? like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you want the `40` to be displayed higher or do you want to display `[0, 40, 80]` or `[0, 40]` instead of `[0, 20, 40]`?

Answer (score 0):

You could just resize the plot image, it should fit to the proportions of your IDE